# Icon SVG criado com Inkscape não é devidamente importado

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

Com aplicação Inkscape, estou a tentar criar os meus próprios icons personalizados em SVG para depois importa-los para o Android Studio. Na importação para o Android Studio recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro `ERROR@ line 29 <defs> is not supported
WARNING@ line 51 We don't scale the stroke width!`  Podem-me ajudar neste erro ou sabem de algum tutorial onde ensine a criar icons SVG para importar para o Android Studio?
Código gerado pelo Android Studio após a importação de um icon SVG de testes:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24.0"
android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:pathData="M12,12m-11.016,0a11.016,11.016 0,1 1,22.032 0a11.016,11.016 0,1 1,-22.032 0"
    android:strokeLineCap="butt"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000"
    android:fillColor="#ff0000"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:strokeLineJoin="miter"
    android:strokeAlpha="1"/>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já tentou converte-los pra PNG?

Comment: Não tentei, porque eu quero o Icon em SVG...

Comment: Poderia mostrar o código que é gerado? assim ajuda a identificar o erro! Parece que ele está usando algo que o Android Studio não entende!

Comment: @Thiago Luiz Domacoski, editei a minha pergunta e acrescentei o código gerado pelo Android Studio após a importação do ficheiro SVG.

Comment: ocorre erro ao criar? ou quando voce roda a aplicação? Aqui não ocorreu nenhum erro! Os passos: 1. Criei um .xml qualquer na pasta drawable; 2. Colei o conteúdo acima! Rodou sem problemas !

Comment: O erro ocorre ao criar. Editei a minha pergunta e adicionei um novo código e um print screen do erro do Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio não suporta a especificação SVG completa. Mas você pode criar gráficos simples, sem gradientes, filtros, etc. usando apenas figuras simples e paths.

`<defs>` é um bloco de cabeçalho SVG, usado para declarar elementos que serão reusados. Os elementos declarados em `<defs>` não são renderizados até que sejam chamados em outra parte do documento. Por exemplo, pode-se declarar um círculo em `<defs>`:

e ele não será desenhado, a menos que seja referenciado em um `<use>`:

```
<svg ...>
    <defs>
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40" fill="blue" id="circulo" />
    </defs>

    <use xlink:href="#circulo" />
    <use xlink:href="#circulo" transform="translate(300,100)" />
<svg>
```

O SVG acima reusa o círculo duas vezes, redesenhando-o em posições diferentes.

Se o `<defs>` não é suportado, você pode muitas vezes alterar o SVG de maneira a não usá-lo. Para funcionar no Android Studio, o SVG teria que ser re-escrito sem o `<defs>`assim:

```
<svg ...>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40" fill="blue" id="circulo" />
    <circle cx="300" cy="100" r="40" fill="blue" id="circulo" />
<svg>
```

Comment: Helderdarocha, obrigado pela sua resposta. Criei o seguinte exemplo de testes para importar para o Android Studio mas mesmo assim não funciona: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg height="24" width="24">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40" fill="blue" id="circulo" />
</svg>. Obtenho o erro:  NumberFormatException: For input string: "lue"

Comment: "lue"? O único lugar em que aparece esse string é em `fill="blue"`. Se o Android Studio não suporta esse atributo, alternativas são "style="fill: blue" ou aplicar o estilo via CSS (`<style> circle {fill: blue} </style>`).

Comment: Você também pode tentar uma biblioteca como svg-android: https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg que alega oferecer suporte completo a todos os componentes gráficos. O repositório tem sido atualizado com freqüência.

Comment: Helderdarocha, obrigado mais uma vez. Vou estudar a biblioteca que você recomendou.

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguem tenha dificuldade com isso, instale essa extensao para o inkscape:
[AndroidVector](https://github.com/owenfromcanada/inkscape-androidvector)
Aqui comigo funcionou direitinho

"Essa extensão adiciona um novo tipo para imagens vetoriais do Android em "Salvar como".
Depois de instalado, selecione **Salvar Como...** ou **Salvar uma Cópia** e você verá um tipo chamado
**Android VectorDrawable (* .xml)** na lista suspensa.

**Instalação**

Copie os arquivos androidvector.py e androidvector.imx para o diretório de extensões.
Num mac com High Sierra fica em `~/.config/inkscape/extensions`.
Num mac com Mojave ou Catalina, fica em `~/Library/Application Support/org.inkscape.Inkscape/config/inkscape/extensions`.

- Recarregue o Inkscape e o novo tipo de salvamento deve estar disponível.

**Uso e limitações**

Atualmente, essa extensão funciona apenas com "paths" e "groups".

Todos os outros objetos precisarão ser convertidos em caminhos antes de salvar o documento; caso contrário, eles não serão representados na imagem vetorial.

Os vetores do Android não suportam gradientes. A extensão tentará usar uma das cores degradê.

Os vetores Android têm implementações de opacidade ligeiramente diferentes.

O Inkscape possui três valores de opacidade para caminhos: traçado, preenchimento e geral.

O Android não tem opacidade geral; portanto, isso é combinado com as opacidades de traço e preenchimento.

O Android Studio tem uma função para reformatar o código. Se você precisar modificar algum atributo no Android Studio, poderá reformatar o XML para facilitar as coisas."

Espero que ajude